# MIPS: What does Add R3, R1, #4 Mean

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-architecture

I'm reading some MIPS code where the assembly code states

```
Add R3, R1, #4
```

I don't understand what the #4  means.  Traditionally # is used for commenting .  Do you think it actually means the immediate or $4 ?  R3 = R1 + $4 ?

Comment: That looks like ARM assembly code.

Comment: What assembler was it written for? Different assemblers, even for the same architecture, use different syntax for immediates, hexadecimal constants, comments, etc.

Comment: traditionally a semicolon is used for commenting.  That looks like ARM with 4 being a constant/immediate.  Dollar sign traditionally means hex, but those older cpus dont necessarily have that many registers nor a two register and an immediate offset, if a register then reg=reg+immediate.

Comment: it could be mips, understand that assembly language (the syntax) is defined by the assembler not the target.  Someone could easily make a MIPS assembler with that syntax.

Comment: In some assembly languages yes that line means r3 = r1 + 4

Comment: which can be understood as `addi $3, $1, 4` in MARS/SPIM simulator, but it's more likely this is ARM bit of source, unless you have whole source using `Rx` for registers and everything else makes sense with MIPS target, then it may be for assembler which has considerably different syntax than the MARS/SPIM family.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes you're right Bill, it denotes an immediate value.